# ISAPI_Rewrite Rule for version 2

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

How can I write the following rule in older version of ISAPI_rewrite ?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fit-reisen.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.fitreisen.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I tried to write like

```
RewriteCond Host: (?!^www.fit-reisen.de)(.+)
RewriteRule /(.*) http\://www.fitreisen.de/$2 [I,RP]
```

but i did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know ISAPI_rewrite very well. But try this:

```
RewriteCond Host: ^fit-reisen\.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http\://www.fitreisen.de$1 [I,RP,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for ISAPI_Rewrite2 should be as follows:

```
RewriteCond Host: fit-reisen\.de
RewriteRule (.*) http\://www.fitreisen.de$1 [RP]
```